# Get selected row value instead of number in shiny using DT

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

Small question here: I know I can access selected rows by `input$dfname_rows_selected` it gives back the numbers of rows selected, but how do I read the rows names, not numbers? In my case they are generated not in the order I use them later, therefore  I need to get the values inside to make it work.

edit: added example

```
ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(

  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
  actionButton("btn", "press me")

))

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    print(input$table_rows_selected)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({

    mtcars %>%
      datatable(selection = "multiple")

  })

}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Comment: ok, i will in a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- basicPage(
  mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput('mytable')),
  textOutput("selected")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  mydata <- reactive({mtcars})

  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable(    
    datatable(mydata())
  ) 

  selectedRow <- eventReactive(input$mytable_rows_selected,{
    row.names(mtcars)[c(input$mytable_rows_selected)]
  })

  output$selected <- renderText({ 
    selectedRow()
  })
}
runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server))
```

Comment: suppose I want only the number from a row of a variable, say `disp`, how can we get it from above?

Comment: @loveR, `mydata()$disp[input$mytable_rows_selected]`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. What you could do is write a reactive, where all modifications to your dataframe take place, before creating the datatable. An example:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"),
  textOutput("selectedcar")
)
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

  # the reactive where we filter/sort/modify the data
  reactive_df <- reactive({
    mtcars[order(mtcars$cyl),]
    })

  # This datatable uses the reactive directly, so no more modifications
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(reactive_df())
    })

  # now we can get the row/rowname as follows:
  output$selectedcar <- renderText({
    paste0(rownames(reactive_df())[input$table_rows_selected], collapse = ", ")
  }) 
} 


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, I added DT:: before the dataTableOutput just to be sure it doesn't use the shiny version, that might have been the issue.

Comment: Florian, do we need to use `paste0`? It makes a vector of `"name1, ", "name2, "` for me, and leaveas a coma if it's empty. Isn't `rownames(reactive_df())[input$table_rows_selected]` enough?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I used paste0 to make the output a bit nicer, you can simple leave that out.